# Can I exclude thumbs from ManipulationEnabled?

Tags: wpf, touch

I have FrameworkElements that have IsManipulationEnabled set to true, that's working nicely, but, there is an issue at my case, its that there is resizing thumbs at the FrameworkElements style.

I need to exclude the thumbs from touch manipulation, because currently when the user moves the thumb with his finger, all the shape is moved instead of resizing it with drag delta at the thumb.

I tried to put IsManipulationEnabled= false at the constructor of the thumbs, but, it didn't work.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve the issue! Ironically, I have set `IsManipulationEnabled` for thumbs to true, then inside thumbs I:

```
protected override void OnManipulationStarting(ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
e.Cancel();
}
```

that's it

Now, thumbs within shape style receive mouse events from touch, and the shape receives manipulation events :-)